# C pointer structure - buffer points to another structure. How to in C#?

Tags: c#, c, pointers, buffer, pascal

This was given to me in C:

```
CDCAInput := PTCDCAInput(@CDCAr);
```

I was only told:
The pointer of the structure TCDCAInput is used by functions to pass additional input fields required for transactions. Buffer to which it points will be filled in response with the CDCAResult structure.

I think the @CDCAr is an instance of the CDCAResult structure.  But not entirely sure about the meaning of the entire line of code.

For someone like me who doesn't know C ... I cannot figure how to write its equivalent in C#.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like C at all, more like Pascal.

Comment: There is no `:=` operator in C, so this isn't C... unless you're using some really nasty macros.

Comment: I also don't have experience in Pascal :)
The function is in C and this is the only code that was provided.
So thanks to your help, I'm guessing this is how it is set up in Pascal. 
Is it possible to do the above in C# with the example in Pascal?

Comment: So if I look at this.
I am going to assume that PTCDCAInput is a base variable of the original CDCAInput which may be the structure CDCAResult.
does that sound right?
So i have to understand how the pointer in Pascal can be translated so I can do the same thing in C#
Thanks for the help BTW.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know C# so I can't fully answer the question, but can explain some things that may help...

It's a common convention in Pascal and Delphi to name structured types (Records and Classes) starting with "T". Another convention is to name pointer types starting with "P".

With those conventions, there is probably a Record (like a C struct) type named `TCDCAInput`, and also a type named `PTCDCAInput` declared as a pointer to a `TCDCAInput`.

`@` is Pascal's "address of" operator, which gives the address of a variable.

Pascal type-casts have a syntax like this: `TypeName(VariableName)`

So overall, the line:

```
CDCAInput := PTCDCAInput(@CDCAr);
```

Means: cast the address of the `CDCAr` variable to the `PTCDCAInput` type, and assign that value to the `CDCAInput` variable.